# Glitch on Freeside

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I was looking at glitches for Fallout: New Vegas on Wikia and... I came across a bug that was talking about how a building near Mick & Ralph's would glitch out and "walk" towards you or something? This made no sense.. How can a building walk? I tried looking it up on YouTube but got no results. Also the way [Wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Freeside) explained it made no sense:

> The building by [Mick & Ralph's](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mick_%26_Ralph%27s) sometimes glitches by standing by one
>   of the corners and walking forward and hitting the Pip-Boy at the same
>   time to fly all the way up the corner of the building and be above and
>   sometime it will summon one on top of the [Lucky 38](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lucky_38).

Comment: Please copy text from websites, don't embed screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation; personally unverified.

The building by Mick & Ralph's sometimes causes a glitch. Stand facing one of the corners and walk forward, hitting the Pip-Boy at the same time. You will fly all the way up the corner of the building and be above it. Sometimes it will even put you on top of the Lucky 38.

Not only are they *not* talking about the building itself, but it's the building *by* M&R's.

Comment: Ohhh I understand now ^^'